# Get inner html of the selected option

Tags: javascript, dom

I have something like this:

```
select = document.getElementById("select");
select.onchange = function(){
  alert(this.value); //returns the selected value
  alert(this.innerHTML); //returns the entire select with all the options
  alert(this.selected.innerHTML); //this is what I want, but doesn't work, of course
};
```

How can I get the innerHTML of the selected option in pure js? (no frameworks).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try:

```
alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
```

Demo:

```html
<select onchange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text)">
  <option>foo
  <option>bar
  <option>foobar
</select>
```

Comment: good call, using js without a library, some IE browsers do not associate innerHTML or nodes with options.

Comment: No need to try this: it is correct and works in all major browsers released since the mid-90s. Have confidence in your answer :)

Comment: There was no uncertainty if my answer may be wrong, but I didn't knew what he likes to do with the result. **text** may return different than **innerHTML** if character-references are used inside the option, so the "try" was more meant as "*try if it is what you're looking for*" :)

Comment: I prefer text. when i fill up options from a async GET request, .innerHTML does not work, but .text works.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested it, but this might work:

```
alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 3):

This will work.

```
select = document.getElementById("select");
select.onchange = function(){
    alert(this.value); //returns the selected value
    alert(this.innerHTML); //returns the entire select with all the options
    var options = this.getElementsByTagName("option");
    var optionHTML = options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML;  
    alert(optionHTML); //this is what I want, but it works now
};
```

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research it appears as though the browser (Chrome anyway) will strip out tags from option values making it impossible to get the actual HTML code.  For example, given the following HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <select>
      <option><b>test 1</b></option>
      <option><b>test 2</b></option>
    </select>
  </body>
</html>
```

- `document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].options[0].text` returns 'test 1'
- `document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].options[0].innerHTML` returns 'test 1'
- `document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].options[0].firstChild` returns a text node containing 'test 1'
- `document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0].firstChild.nextSibling` returns the first option node.  Its first child is the text node 'test 1'

Comment: Thanks, my intentions was .text (I didn't know it existed), but this is interesting to know.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using this snippet:

```
alert(this.selectedOptions[0].text)
```

Demo:

```html
<select onchange="alert(this.selectedOptions[0].text)">
  <option value="1">one</option>
  <option value="2">two</option>
  <option value="3">three</option>
</select>
```

The ***selectedOptions*** is an HTML collection which contains all selected options. Using this snippet gives more advantage than **this.options[this.selectedIndex]** when you are using multi-select. In the case of a **multi-select dropdown**, ***this.selectedOptions*** **will contain all selected elements**. You can iterate through this collection to get innerHTML of all selected items.