# Selection from dropdownlist javascript event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, dom

I have this html part code :

```
 <p><label>Taxe </label>
    <select id="id_taxe" name="id_taxe" style="width: 100px;" onchange="taxselection(this);"></select>
    <input id="taxe" name="taxe" class="fiche" width="150px" readonly="readonly" />%
</p>
```

**Javascript method** :

```
function taxselection(cat)
{
    var tax = cat.value;
    alert(tax);
    $("#taxe").val(tax);
}
```

I'd like to set the value of `taxe` input to the selected value from the dropdownlist.It works fine only where the dropdownlist contains more than one element.

I try `onselect` instead of `onchange` but I get the same problem.

So How can I fix this issue when the list contains only one element?

Comment: try wiith innerhtml also here look at this one too might give you some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069294/get-inner-html-of-the-selected-option

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/z2uao1un/ -edit- I now see what your problem is. Yeah onchange means it has to trigger the change event, with no options there is never a change.

Comment: @Mikey my problem is when I have ONLY one element not two

Comment: @LamloumiAfif Yeah I see, I've posted a workaround as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
$('#id_taxe').change(function(){
  var thisVal = $(this).val();
  var curVal = $('#taxe').val();

  if(thisVal != curVal)
    $('#taxe').val(thisVal);
  $('#select option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
  $(this).attr('selected','selected');
});
```

Use the change method which is very efficient for select boxes. Simply check the item selected isn't currently selected then if not, set the value of the input to the selected value. Lastly you want to remove any option's attr's that are "selected=selected" and set the current one to selected.

Just include this inside a $(document).ready() wrapper at the end of your HTML and the change event will be anchored to the select field.

Hope this helps.

http://jsbin.com/populo

Comment: My code works fine. I have problem ONLY when I have one element

Comment: Then you need to insert a blank 'Please select an option' option. http://jsbin.com/populo/ - See revised method. Its not polite to the user to present them a form that already has options selected, its always best to have a preselect option and it makes changes easier to handle as well as form validation. As if your user 'forgot' to change the value, if there was no default 'Please select an option' you wouldn't necessarily realise during validation

Answer (score 1):

Either always give an empty option, or in your code that outputs the select, check the amount of options, and set the input value straight away if there's only 1 option.

A select with just 1 option has no events, since the option will be selected by default, so there's no changes, and no events.

Answer (score 0):

As DrunkWolf mentioned add an empty option always or you can try onblur or  onclick event instead, depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, just to stay close to your code, do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/z2uao1un/1/

```
function taxselection(cat) {
    var tax = cat.value;
    alert(tax);
    $("#taxe").val(tax);
}

taxselection(document.getElementById('id_taxe'));
```

This will call the function onload and get value of the element. You can additionally add an onchange eventhandler to the element. I highly recommend **not** doing that in the HTML! Good luck.