# Getting inner text values from a select list with C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to extract option values as well as the text between the option tags from a select list.

```
body>
<select name="country" id="id_country">
    <option value="">Select a country...</option>
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AX">Åland Islands</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
    <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
    <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
    <option value="AO">Angola</option>
```

I have tried the following which makes sense to me.

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(sb.ToString());

            var values = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("option").Select(n => new
             {
                 Value = n.Attributes["value"].Value,
                 Text = n.InnerHtml,
             }).ToList();
```

and managed to get the option value but not the country name between the tags.

return this instead.

```
 Value="AF", Text="",
Value="AX", Text="",
```

etc.
How can I return the values as well?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069294/get-inner-html-of-the-selected-option

Comment: @FᴀʀʜᴀɴAɴᴀᴍ I think he wants to get all values from the `options` at once and not just the selected one.

Comment: @diiN_ Yes you are right but the linked answer states that using `innerHTML` should produce the correct output....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing HTML with HtmlAgillityPack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758644/parsing-html-with-htmlagillitypack)

Comment: The OP is using Html Agility Pack which does not behave according to normal HTML DOM standards.

Comment: @NineBerry Good point...

Comment: Cool, thanks...managed with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758644/parsing-html-with-htmlagillitypack)

Answer (score -1):

Should be using n.InnerText rather then InnerHtml.