# Getting values from inside the HTML tag

Tags: javascript

I am using `element.innerHTML` to retrive a value from a drop down clicked element:

```
    $(b).on('click','#input',function(){
        console.log('on click fired')
        /*insert the value for the autocomplete text field:*/
        inpStr=this.innerHTML
        inp.value = this.innerHTML
        /*close the list of autocompleted values,
        (or any other open lists of autocompleted values:*/
        closeAllLists();
    })
```

Now the InnerHTML looks something like this:

```
<div class="col-4 querySelect">23</div>
<div class="col-4">2019-04-04</div>
<div class="col-4">Main</div>
```

I just want the value 23 from this. I think there is a way to do this using regex but I thought it would be better using dom selectors so I did:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".col-4")
                for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
                inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
                    inp.value = inputs[i]
                    console.log(inputs[i])
                });
                }
```

But it returns nothing

What would be the best way to retrieve the value from this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069294/get-inner-html-of-the-selected-option this may help ..

Comment: The elements you work with don't have a `value`. Maybe you are looking for their `textContent`? Then: What is `inp` which is coming out of nowhere? Next: You have never declared your index variable `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Query Selector will Do,moreover if you are looking for varied options,I have added in answer.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelector(".col-4"); // returns first Elment
console.log(inputs.textContent)

// with Query Selector All
var inputs2 = document.querySelectorAll(".col-4"); // returns all element

inputs2.forEach(ele => {
  // check for the particulr class
  if (ele.getAttribute("class") == "col-4 querySelect") {
 console.log(ele.textContent)
}
})
// for only query select class
var inputs3 = document.querySelector(".querySelect"); // returns first Elment
console.log(inputs3.textContent)
```

```html
<div class="col-4 querySelect">23</div>
<div class="col-4">2019-04-04</div>
<div class="col-4">Main</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the `forEach` one and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Because the element you want has a `className` of `querySelect`, just use that query string:

```
inp.value = document.querySelector('.querySelect').textContent;
```

When retrieving the contents of an input-like element, reference its `value` - when retrieving the contents of any other type of element, reference its `textContent`. (referencing just the element itself won't do anything useful)

Comment: The element you're suggesting to query **does not have a `value`**.

Comment: Oops, of course, it's a normal element, not an input-like element

Comment: You should specifically elaborate on this part, because this is the main reason OP's approach won't work.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that `inp` was never declared let alone initialized as an object, so `inp.value = ...` will throw a `cannot assign value of undefined` error.